# Why won't the SQL Server partitioning function return more partition numbers?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, azure-sql-database

### Context

A `partition function` is used to horizontally partition a table or index in SQL Server. It identifies the partition boundaries and indicates the behavior of the range - that is from LEFT to RIGHT of the boundary.

- Read more in the [online docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/partitions/create-partitioned-tables-and-indexes?view=sql-server-ver16).

Here's a simple example of a partition function:

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM sys.partition_functions WHERE name = 'year_partition_function')
  DROP PARTITION FUNCTION year_partition_function;

CREATE PARTITION FUNCTION year_partition_function (INT) AS 
  RANGE LEFT FOR VALUES (2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009 
                        ,2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019 
                        ,2020, 2021, 2022, 2023, 2024, 2025, 2026, 2027, 2028, 2029, 2030);
```

### The setup

Using `$PARTITION` in TSQL we can query a partition function with a sample value for the resulting, calculated partition. It is a handy way to debug how a function behaves. In the sample below, I am calling the function created above with one of every value - matching the boundaries exactly - just to see the range of partitions it will return.

- Read more in the [online docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/partition-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16).

```
WITH years AS
(
  SELECT s.value AS Value
  FROM STRING_SPLIT('2000,2001,2002,2003,2004,2005,2006,2007,2008,2009' +
                   ',2010,2011,2012,2013,2014,2015,2016,2017,2018,2019' +
                   ',2020,2021,2022,2023,2024,2025,2026,2027,2028,2029,2030',',') AS s
)
, parts as 
(
  SELECT Value
    , $PARTITION.customer_partition_function(Value) AS [ParitionNumber]
  FROM years
)
SELECT [ParitionNumber]
  , STRING_AGG(Value, ',') AS Boundaries
FROM parts
GROUP BY [ParitionNumber]
```

### The question

I would have expected the results of this query to have as many partitions as there were boundaries I passed in. Each one was unique and each one was listed as a boundary in the partition function. Instead, I only get a few partitions.

**Q: Why don't I get more partitions in this test of the function?**

Actual results:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

⚠️ This error occurs when you are testing the incorrect partition function! How embarrassing.

> I will leave this question here anyway since it has a lot of useful information for anyone trying to get partitions setup & tested.

**The correct test query:**

```
WITH years AS
(
  SELECT s.value AS Value
  FROM STRING_SPLIT('2000,2001,2002,2003,2004,2005,2006,2007,2008,2009' +
                   ',2010,2011,2012,2013,2014,2015,2016,2017,2018,2019' +
                   ',2020,2021,2022,2023,2024,2025,2026,2027,2028,2029,2030',',') AS s
)
, parts as 
(
  SELECT Value
    , $PARTITION.year_partition_function(Value) AS [ParitionNumber]
  FROM years
)
SELECT [ParitionNumber]
  , STRING_AGG(Value, ',') AS Boundaries
FROM parts
GROUP BY [ParitionNumber]
```

Actual results (as expected):

[image]